# Javascript: evaluate and return inline text

Tags: javascript, inline

I have a strange question. I have an application that sends text in an HTML format. For example:

```
My text text <b>bold text</b>
```

I would like to add dynamic text based on javascript logic that would evaluate and return the text inline.

For example:

```
 My text text <script>if (a == b) return "bla bla"; else return "alb alb";</script>
```

The thing is, I can't access any element from the dom to manually inject the text (document.getElementById... etc...)

Is there a possible without using any external library or accessing the DOM?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it could seem stupid, but have you tried `document.write()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "the application _sends_ text"? Sends where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `document.write()`

check [this](http://jsbin.com/udogil/1/)